# Stacking ResourceT monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'd like to stack `ResourceT` with the `ReaderT` monad. It seems I have two options: 
Either place `ReaderT` on the bottom or at the top of the stack.

```
data MyEnv

newtype MyT1 m a = MyT1 { unT1 :: ResourceT (ReaderT MyEnv m) a }

newtype MyT2 m a = MyT2 { unT2 :: ReaderT MyEnv (ResourceT m) a }
```

What would be better in sence of performance/correctness? What are the general guidelines for stacking `ResourceT` with `WriterT` or other monads?

Comment: Interestingly, `ResourceT` is itself just a specialized `ReaderT` monad—all of the interesting stuff gets executed in lifted IO actions. I haven't benched it, but my guess is that both stacks are equally fast. Furthermore, Readers commute (via `flip`) so the two stacks ought to be semantically identical.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson's comments looks like the right answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as correctness goes, they are both equally correct -- see comments by @J.Abrahamson and @Michael Snoyman.

Performance probably depends on use, in particular it will change how many calls to lift cross that particular layer, which should be the main performance difference.  I'd imagine most fair benchmarks would show little to no difference.  For whole program performance, profiling is king.